# What is the reason for interpreting word Imam to book in Quran?

Tags: tafseer, arabic, quran-translation

The word "imam" simply means "imam", but some interpreters (Mofasers) like Ibn Katheer have interpreted the word to mean "book". Why interpret it to "book"?

> يَوۡمَ نَدۡعُواْ ڪُلَّ أُنَاسِۭ بِإِمَـٰمِهِمۡ‌ۖ فَمَنۡ أُوتِىَ
> ڪِتَـٰبَهُ ۥ بِيَمِينِهِۦ فَأُوْلَـٰٓٮِٕكَ يَقۡرَءُونَ ڪِتَـٰبَهُمۡ
> وَلَا يُظۡلَمُونَ فَتِيلاً۬ (٧١)
>
> Think of) the Day when We will call every people with their books of
> deeds. Then the ones who will be given their book in their right hands
> will read their book (happily) and will not be wronged even to the
> measure of a fine thread. (71)
>
> Suratul Isra' Ayah 71

**Source: [Tafseer Ibn Katheer](http://qurancomplex.org/Quran/tafseer/Tafseer.asp?nSora=36&t=katheer&l=arb&nAya=12#36_12)**

---

Some Translations of this verse are:

One day We shall call together all human beings with their (respective) Imams.  [Ahmed Ali]

On the day when We shall summon every group along with its leader [Ahmed Raza Khan]

Then think of the Day We shall summon every community with its leader. [Abul Ala Maududi]

(Remember) the day when We will call every people with their Imam; [Mohammad Habib Shakir]

The Day will surely come when We shall summon every people with their leader.[Wahiduddin Khan]

*1. What is the reason for this interpret?*

*2. Is there any hadith saying Imam means book?*

Answer (score 6):

There are three good tafseers for the word *imam* here:

- book (record)
- prophet
- leader

**The first one** is the strongest one, in my opinion, because it has many evidences from other ayat (verse):

this is the evidence that imam could mean book:

> and what they left behind, and all things We have enumerated in a
>   clear register. [Surat Yā-Sīn](http://quran.com/36/12)

There are many other ayat indicate that people are called with their books (records):

> Every nation will be called to its record. [Surat Al-Jāthiyah](http://quran.com/45/28)

---

> And the record [of deeds] will be placed (open). [Surat Al-Kahf](http://quran.com/18/49)

---

> and We will produce for him on the Day of Resurrection a record which
>   he will encounter spread open. [Surat Al-'Isrā'](http://quran.com/17/13)

And when you complete the aya you mentioned you'll find:

> Then the ones who will be given their book in their right hands will
>   read their book ...

**The tafseer with prohet** is strong too:

> So when their messenger comes, it will be judged between them in
>   justice. [Surat Yūnus](http://quran.com/10/47)

---

> So how [will it be] when We bring from every nation a witness and we
>   bring you, [O Muhammad] against these [people] as a witness. [Surat
>   An-Nisā'](http://quran.com/4/41)

---

> And [mention] the Day when We will resurrect among every nation a
>   witness over them from themselves. And We will bring you, [O
>   Muhammad], as a witness over your nation. [Surat An-Naĥl](http://quran.com/16/89)

---

> and the record [of deeds] will be placed, and the prophets and the
>   witnesses will be brought. [Surat Az-Zumar](http://quran.com/39/69)

**The tafseer with leader** could be right because in another aya:

> And We made them leaders inviting to the Fire, and on the Day of
>   Resurrection they will not be helped. [Surat Al-Qaşaş](http://quran.com/28/41)

Finally, some people say that imam means the book revealed to one's prophet.

Allah knows best.